# How can I implement an object of strategies with same API but that only the provided argument options differ for each strategy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, strategy-pattern

Right now I am struggling with pleasing TypeScript compiler when using generics.
I am trying to implement a strategy pattern selector using a JavaScript object. Every strategy shares the same API with several methods, where the only difference is the argument provided for some of the methods of the API, that are options diverse between the different strategies.

This is the code I implemented:

```
enum Strategy {
    One,
    Two,
    ...
}

export interface StrategiesApi<TOptions> {
    delete(): void;
    execute(options: TOptions): void;
}

export type Strategies<TOptions> = {
    [key in Strategy]: StrategiesApi<TOptions>;
};


const strategies = {
    [Strategy.One]: {
        delete: strategyOneDelete,
        execute: strategyOneExecute,
        ...
    },
    [Strategy.Two]: {
        delete: strategyTwoDelete,
        execute: strategyTwoExecute,
        ...
    },
};
```

When I am trying to use a function for selecting the strategy like this:

```
export const getStrategy = <TOptions>(strategy: Strategy): StrategyApi<TOptions> => {
    const strategy = strategies[strategy];

    if (!strategy) {
        throw new Error('Strategy not found');
    }

    return strategy;
};
```

TypeScript complains about TOptions not to be assignable to the belonging type of the strategy for the argument `options` in the `execute` method.

I can fix it explicitly typing the return to avoid that compilation error as:

```
    ...
    return strategy as StrategyApi<TOptions>;
};
```

But I do not think is a good idea as it removes the TypeScript type validation.

What would be the best way of implementing this strategy pattern selection with generic argument options? I'd like to avoid having to be completely explicit either in the return type or change the implementation by building a explicit `Strategies` interface type such:

```
export interface Strategies {
    [Strategy.One]: {
        delete(): void;
        execute(options: StrategyOneOptions): void;
    },
    [Strategy.Two]: {
        delete(): void;
        execute(options: StrategyTwoOptions): void;
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: You declare a `type Strategies<TOptions>` but you're not using it. Did you mean to declare the `strategies` variable with that type?

Comment: The strategies should not be generic. To implement a proper strategy pattern, all strategy implementations need to take the *same* options type, otherwise how would you ever be able to call `getStrategy(…).execute` if you don't know what options object to pass?

Comment: @Bergi regarding the type, yes, but fails as if doing ```const strategies: Strategies<TOptions>``` fails for missing `TOptions`.

Regarding the second point, probably that's part of my whole problem. The usage of the different strategies share an options Object (let's think in a reusable config object) but then each strategy should only use certain properties that I try to make explicit inside the `execute` method argument.

Comment: If they share an options object, you should use the type of that options object as the generic type parameter in `const strategies: Strategies<…>`, and not make `getStrategy` generic at all but have it return a `StrategyApi<…>` with that type. (Or even get rid of the type parameter in the `StrategyApi` definition). Any `execute` implementation is free to use only a subset of the properties. You can also make that explicit and define them with their own parameter type, then declare `type SharedOptions = StrategyOneExecuteOptions & StrategyTwoExecuteOptions & …`.